# Building an application in android studio 2.3 and i keep having this error:

Tags: gridview

Error:08:42:31.074: WARNING: com.android.jack.Options: Incremental mode is disabled due to multi-dex legacy mode

Comment: what is programming language you use

Comment: java_8 using lambdas

Comment: then add the tag as java , describe your question and  add codes you have in your application